# Sync between Mac & PC version control system

Tags: data-synchronization, dropbox, git, pc, google-apps

Having both a PC & Mac for work, I would like to synchronize development between both devices. I could just use Dropbox or Google Drive, but I would like to have version control (git or otherwise).

Is there a way to run a version control system (git preferably) between these two devices?

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same question a while ago, and I decided against a solution based on Dropbox or similar tools.

Take a look at https://bitbucket.org/ - they offer free private Git repositories.

If you don't mind hosting your stuff on a public repo, you could also use GitHub, but if it has to be private, check out BitBucket. This is a real Git host, so you can pull/push, even if your machines are on different networks.

Dropbox always sounded like the wrong way for this. It can certainly work, but why do it like this when you can use a real Git host for free?

Answer (score 1):

Several ways.

The one I use is use a source directory on the local PC or MAc drive and then push to a git clone in a dropbox directory. I can then pull from or push to the dropbox directory locally and dropbox symcs to the other machines.

If both machines are on the same network you can create a [git server](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server) on one (easier on the Mac) and push/pull to the other machine

Comment: Is it possible to use a git client on each machine to work with the dropbox repo?

Comment: Yes that is what I tried to explain